Minimal condition for independence to imply conditional independence
Independence of random variables does not in general imply conditional independence. However, if the conditioning variable is independent of one of the variables, does conditional independence hold?
To make it mathematically precise, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent ($X$ and $Z$ could be dependent). Does this imply $Y$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent conditioning on $X$?
My intuition is that this is not sufficient, and independence imply conditional independence only if the three variables are mutually independent, but I could not come up with a counterexample.

Say you are tossing a fair penny and a fair dime.  Let $X$ be the indicator variable for Heads on the penny, $Y$ the same for the dime, $Z$ the indicator for the event $X=Y$.

Your intuition is right. You need mutual independence of $X,Y,Z$.
Consider the following counterexample:
Let $X, Y, Z$ be Bernoulli random variables, each taking values in $\{0,1\}$, defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
    X &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right), \\
    Y &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \quad \text{(independent of \(X\))}, \\
    Z &= X \oplus Y = (X+Y)\pmod{2}.
\end{align*}
